# Почему когда я ипользую Babel['transform'] возникает ошибка Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token

Tags: веб-программирование, reactjs, компоненты

Это полный класс React

```
let template = config['babel']['transform'](`        
       let React =   config['React']
      let connect =   config['connect']
      let PropTypes = config['PropTypes']
      let Component = config['Component']
      let loginUser = config['actions']['authActions']['loginUser']
             let store = config['store']

        class Login extends Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
              email: '',
              password: '',
              errors: {}
            };
          }

          componentDidMount() {
            if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
              this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
            }
          }

          componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
              this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
            }

            if (nextProps.errors) {
              this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
            }
          }
          onSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!eee!!!!!', this)
            const userData = {
              email: this.state.email,
              password: this.state.password
            };

            this.props.loginUser(userData);
          }

          onChange = e => {
            console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!eee!!!!!', this)
            this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
          }
          render() {
            const { errors } = this.state;

            return (
              <div className="login">
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
                      <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Log In</h1>
                      <p className="lead text-center">
                        Sign in to your DevConnector account
                      </p>
                      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <TextFieldGroup
                          placeholder="Email Address"
                          name="email"
                          type="email"
                          value={this.state.email}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          error={errors.email}
                        />

                        <TextFieldGroup
                          placeholder="Password"
                          name="password"
                          type="password"
                          value={this.state.password}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          error={errors.password}
                        />
                        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

      Login.propTypes = {
        loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
      };

      const mapStateToProps = state => ({

        auth: state.auth,
        errors: state.errors
      });
      resolve(connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(Login))
            `,config['babel']['availablePresets']['react'])
      eval(template.code)
```

Когда я использую Babel'transform' у меня появляется следующая ошибка для данного кода.

```
 onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!eee!!!!!', this)
    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  }

  onChange = e => {
    console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!eee!!!!!', this)
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
```

```
    Login.js:109 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (34:19)
      32 |             }
      33 |           }
    > 34 |           onSubmit = e => {
         |                    ^
      35 |             e.preventDefault();
      36 |             console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!eee!!!!!', this)
      37 |             const userData = {
        at t.J.raise (babel.js:4)
        at t.X.unexpected (babel.js:4)
        at t.z.parseClassProperty (babel.js:4)
        at t.eval [as parseClassProperty] (babel.js:4)
        at t.z.parseClassBody (babel.js:4)
        at t.z.parseClass (babel.js:4)
        at t.z.parseStatement (babel.js:4)
        at t.eval [as parseStatement] (babel.js:4)
        at t.z.parseBlockBody (babel.js:4)
        at t.z.parseTopLevel (babel.js:4)

Тот же код хорошо работает если не использовать Babel standalone
```

Comment: к настройкам babel добавьте плагин `@babel/proposal-class-properties`

Comment: понять бы ещё как ) Я настройки Babel из самого Babel-я беру.
config['babel']['availablePresets']['react']
Надо разобраться будет.

Comment: Понял как вставляется. Я правильно понимаю, так как это строки, я могу этот код на стороне сервера рендерить и отдавать клиенту ?
p.s. я пока контекст определил для старой записи.
            this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
            this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);